# iOS, AFNetworking and Rails/Devise

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, afnetworking

I've tried searching for examples and answers on this subject but all seemed to be more specific or not exactly relevant to my issue. I'm fairly new to Rails and an intermediate iOS developer. I'm looking to use Rails as a backend to drive a user login based app. I've tried to find example code of how to authenticate with devise using AFHTTPClient but have had no success. The iOS code I am using is:

```
- (IBAction)submitLogin:(id)sender {
    NSString *username = usernameField.text;
    NSString *password = passwordField.text;
    [[AFTestClient sharedClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:username password:password];
    [[AFTestClient sharedClient] postPath:@"login/" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"Success");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}];
}
```

and this is the controller I have set up in Rails with /login matching to activities#login:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:login, :index]

def login
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :text => "#{@user.id}"} 
    format.xml {render :text => "#{@user.id}" }   
  end
end

def index
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :text => "Current user is logged in."} 
    format.xml {render :text => "#{@user.id}" }   
    format.json
  end
end
end
```

I know my standard requests that don't require authentication are going through but I'm assuming the Authentication Header is not being recognized by Devise or something along those lines.

Any responses would be greatly appreciated, especially examples to similar code accomplishing the same task.

Thanks!

Comment: Im trying to understand exactly the same thing. Sad No replies as yet :(

Answer (score 6):

Try to enable basic http authentication in your Rails App's config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
```

There's more information on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication.